# Trying to create a Excel Product formula Manual to Dynamic

Tags: excel-formula

I have been using Product formula manually since long to make calculations but now i want to make it work as Dynamic formula works.

But my result is not matching.

Below is the sheet link where both formulas are.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w5PBoIycEFbjEW0tdOTZ1NDmvtqeHLw4/edit#gid=278652113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following in `G3` reproduces the data & result of `F3`:
`=product(iferror(index(C:C,match(E2, A:A,0)),$A$1),filter(B:C,(A:A<E3)*(A:A>E2)),index(B:B,match(E3,A:A,0)))-1`

For the first value I added a little workaround because your list is lacking January 1st of 2020. (That's the IFERROR directing to `$A$1`. I'm sure there's a cleaner solution for that, but.. it works.

The FILTER function is for Office 365.
For older excel versions use the following:
`=product(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)-1,1),OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(E2,A:A,0),,COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&E3,A:A,">"&E2),2),OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(E3,A:A,0),,,))-1`

To workaround the value not being found for January 1st, 2020 I added this manually in `A1`

Comment: P.b, Thank you so much for the help. Can you please share that how it will work in Microsoft Excel 2016.

Comment: Oh, the filter formula does not work in versions prior to office 365. Sorry.

Comment: But since your dates are in order you could create dynamic ranges using offset.

Comment: P.b, Sir if its possible then please make with offset. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: I will look at it later.

Comment: I would really appreciate.

Comment: I made a beginning in column I, where I replaced the filter (as text in column J) with offset (as text in column K). But the results are off.. I'm working from my mobile, so that's far from ideal. I'll look at it later, but maybe you get the deal by this approach..

Comment: P.b, Sir thank you so much for the given help. You are really a gentle man